# How can I curve a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to copy a design like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK2Zx.png) I tried creating a custom layout to make an arc but the image wont go behind the layout. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9op2T.png) what it looks like. any other Idea how can I achieve the design?

here's my code for arc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#00885588"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000"
                />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

layout_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="182dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arc"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="173dp"
            android:layout_height="179dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That needs a custom View Group.

The easiest solution is to use:

https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout

Comment: that's good but i think it cannot make a 2 image inside of it

Comment: I will check if i can setview inside of it when i have time. Else it will need to be forked and edited

Comment: what do you mean by setview?

Comment: nvm I have solve it by making a layout horizontal inside the arclayout.ArcLayout thankyou very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

make a drawablexml file with below shown code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>  
<item android:top="-250dp"
    android:bottom="350dp"
    android:left="-200dp"
    android:right="-200dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-0"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="?android:colorBackground"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

and use it as background to your layout it will solve your problem

Comment: @Pol Imbing clearly tell me your problem how to design your layout the above which i sent to you surely have to give curve background